# PHPUnit 5.1.3: assertEquals() not working. Error: No tests executed

Tags: phpunit, assert

I need to compare two arrays in phpunit. I am using asserequals() but output shows No Tests Executed! I am mentioning my arrays below and code too:

```
$expected_arr = array('success' => 1);
$result_array =(output of print_r($result_array))
Array
(
    [success] => 1
)
$this->assertEquals($arr_data,$expected_arr);
```

My PHPUnit version is 5.1.3. I am running is on Ubuntu 16

UPDATED:

```
<?php

require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php');

class abc_auto_testing_test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public $abc_id;
    public $abc_answer;

    public function __construct($ABC_id, $ABC_answer)
    {
        $this->abc_id = $ABC_id;
        $this->abc_answer = $ABC_answer;
        $this->test_Abc_Validate($this->abc_id, $this->abc_answer);
   }

   public function setUp()
   {

   }

   public function tearDown()
   {

   }

   public function test_Abc_Validate($abcId, $abcAnswer)
   {
       $expected_arr = array('success' => 1);
       // var_dump($expected_arr);
       $arr_data = ABC_Validate($abcId, $abcAnswer);
       // var_dump($arr_data);
       $this->assertEquals($arr_data,$expected_arr);
    }

}

  require'/var/www/data.abc.in/abc_server_crons/abc_auto_testing_bkp.php';
  $ABC_identifier = $abcIdentifier;
  $ABC_answer = $abcAnswer;
  $validObj = new abc_auto_testing_test($ABC_identifier, $ABC_answer);
?>
```

Comment: How is your test method/class defined?

Comment: @JakubZalas Please have a look i have updated my code with class and method defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your test code makes no sense. Go [here](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html) to learn the basics of writing and running tests.